# Adding transparent border around badge

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am attempting to do something like this: Where the badge in the corner has a transparent border the cuts through the image into the background color.

[image]

I have this play going: https://play.tailwindcss.com/1DYry38e5z but can't seem to get the badge transparent border working properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I want to reuse this avatar in various places without having to worry about what background it is on in each place. For example, our sidebar's background is non white, whereas the body is white. I want this solution to work on both ideally with no extra configuration

Answer (score 0):

Is this your answer?

```html
<span class="absolute right-0 h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-green-600 border-2 border-white"></span>
```

Comment: This only would work on backgrounds that are white. I am looking for a solution that will work with any background color without needed to hardcode it

Answer (score 0):

Just Reduce the border transparency to to your needs

```
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
```

in this case .5 means 50% transparent, just reduce it to .0 and everything will be good.